# How to retrieve a list of ets keys without scanning entire table?

Tags: elixir, ets

I'm using ets via elixir as a simple in-memory persistence layer to store and retrieve keys and also for the occasional foldl which involves reducing many duplicate keys that have different values. I am using the bag option.

Is there a simple, perhaps O(1) way to retrieve a list of just the current keys without having to do a more involved table traversal or match or foldl?

Erlang or Elixir syntax responses welcome.

```
:ets.new(:cache, [:bag, :named_table, :protected])
```

I have a static map of atom keys indexed by integer I am using to assist with insertions.  But not all the keys are used..

```
chunk_key_map = %{2 => :chunk_key_2, ..... 28 => :chunk_key_28}
```

If there's no quick way, I am aware I can do an ets:lookup trying each of my static atom key values and testing for != [] and generating my own list, but wanted to see if ets supports such a feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I didn't find the ets technique, but rather implemented the key list retrieve code in constant time in elixir as my key map is static.

```
    list = Enum.reduce(2..28, [], fn head, acc -> 
            case :ets.lookup(:cache, Map.get(chunk_key_map, head)) do
                [] -> acc
                _ -> [acc, head]
            end
        end)

    List.flatten(list)
```

UPDATE: Based on the replies, I took Hamidreza's `ets` 
traversal logic and wrapped it into an Elixir `Stream` using `Stream.resource/3`.

```
defp get_ets_keys_lazy(table_name) when is_atom(table_name) do
    eot = :"$end_of_table"

    Stream.resource(
        fn -> [] end,

        fn acc ->
            case acc do
                [] -> 
                    case :ets.first(table_name) do
                        ^eot -> {:halt, acc}
                        first_key -> {[first_key], first_key}                       
                    end

                acc -> 
                    case :ets.next(table_name, acc) do  
                        ^eot -> {:halt, acc}
                        next_key -> {[next_key], next_key}
                    end
            end
        end,

        fn _acc -> :ok end
    )
end
```

Then I ran the stream through a pipeline

```
get_ets_keys_lazy(table_name) 
    |> Stream.map(lambda1) 
    |> Stream.each(lambda2)
    |> Stream.run
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that you end up copying all the elements in the ETS table into your process. Remember that ETS tables are kept "outside" of all process so all access to ETS tables is through copying. One major reason for `match`, `match_object` and `select` is that it allows you to be more specific in what elements are copied, testing can be done while the element data is still "in the table".

Comment: Thank you Robert. I am assuming you are only referring to the ets.lookup code segment. Not the ets.first,next snippet as well above? This is very helpful. What then is the appropriate match or select clause for key retrieval?

Comment: Yes, using first/next means that you will access every element, though it does mean that you maybe able to only copy the keys.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks, that put me on the right track :)

Same thing but passing the previous key as accumulator:

```
def key_stream(table_name) do
  Stream.resource(
    fn -> :ets.first(table_name) end,
    fn :"$end_of_table" -> {:halt, nil}
       previous_key -> {[previous_key], :ets.next(table_name, previous_key)} end,
    fn _ -> :ok end)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For getting a list of keys in `ets` without touching their values you can use the combination of `ets:first/1` and `ets:next/2` functions this way:

```
-export([keys/1]).

keys(TableName) ->
    FirstKey = ets:first(TableName),
        keys(TableName, FirstKey, [FirstKey]).

keys(_TableName, '$end_of_table', ['$end_of_table'|Acc]) ->
    Acc;
keys(TableName, CurrentKey, Acc) ->
    NextKey = ets:next(TableName, CurrentKey),
    keys(TableName, NextKey, [NextKey|Acc]).
```

The exported API is `keys/1`. It gets the table name, fetches the first key of it, initiates an accumulator as state and internally calls `keys/2` which fetches other keys and accumulating them in a recursive manner.

Note that `bag` tables type do not have order, so if your table type is `bag` the return value of `keys/1` wouldn't be ordered.

Comment: Since bags are allowed to have duplicate keys but with different values, will this return all the duplicate keys?

Comment: I verified that it does return only the unique keys

Comment: @Heron28 Actually there is no duplicate key in `bag` and `duplicate_bag` tables. The `bag` tables can have many unique values per key and `duplicate_bag` tables can have many duplicated values per key.